# Getting information from a third party Wiki page

Tags: java, mediawiki-api

In the project I am working on I need to access information from the website explainxkcd.com which gives the explanation of specific xkcd comics. The information I am looking for would be the explanation of the comic as a string. Explainxkcd is a site that runs using mediawiki, software that forms a template for the "wiki" feel. Mediawiki has an api that allows you to extract information from their websites and I have gone to [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page) trying to figure out how to use their API for this particular wiki site but to no avail. It seems that you can replace the "index.php" in a URL with api.php to use the API but when I try this for http://explainxkcd.com/9/api.php it doesn't seem to work. I guess my URL is wrong but I don't see any information on how to find the specific URL to use for Explainxkcd.com

QUESTION:

How can I access information from a third party wikipedia page in a Java program? This can be through the mediawiki api or some other solution. If you know a good way to find the URL that can be used with mediawiki that would be preferred. Just looking for a nudge in the right direction here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same method, s/index.php/api.php/, I get a different result: http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/api.php which seems to work. If a wiki is using pretty URLs (e.g. `example.com/wiki/Main_Page`), just click on edit, view source or history.

Yes, please use the API instead of screen-scraping. You can see a few existing Java libraries for that [here](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/api.php).

Comment: That seems to work within my browser, however I am still getting a HTML 403 error which is probably caused by my User-Agent. Could you suggest a way to implement your answer using java? @MaxSem

Comment: But _what_ did you do to get a 403?

Comment: `URL url2 = new URL("http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/api.php");
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(url2.openStream()));
  StringBuffer bufferReader = new StringBuffer();
          String inputLine;
          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
              bufferReader.append(inputLine);` @MaxSem

Comment: I was using the API Sandbox to play around with the different parameters. The one I need to return the explanation portion of a comic isn't supported by ExplainXKCD.com. I want to use the prop=extract function but I don't know what an equivalent that is supported by the website would be.